# Is there a shortcut for SSMS pressing "Enter"

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If I press Enter then the cursor moves to the first indented line.

[[image: before]]

[[image: after pressing "Enter"]]

Is there a Enter like Shortcut to jump to the first position of the next line, like here.

[[image: should be]]

I tried already STRG + Enter, Shift + Enter but nothing worked.

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)
Nov  6 2020 16:50:01

Comment: Why you need to copy it?

Comment: Can't you just press  `Home` after you have pressed `Enter`? This is as many key strokes as `Ctrl + Enter` or similar. Or if you prefer to think of it as a keyboard shortcut, think of it as `Enter + Home`.

Comment: I could press "Enter" and then "Pos1" but I have to press to keyword. Are their a shorter way? Finding Pos1 is also very non intuative. I need a shortcut solution

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. At first glance I assumed the `SELECT` was aligned left. I definitely agree that finding Pos1 is not intuitive, and one reason why I don't align my code as Microsoft does when they generate code like the above. Keeping `SELECT` and `FROM` right aligned rather than left is significantly more hassle than it is worth in my view! I am sure there are those that would disagree though, the nuances of how to format SQL will probably divide people for the rest of time

Comment: Yeah, right justified code is pure evil. This behaviour is controlled in tools>options>text editor>transact sql>tabs. With "block" selected the cursor will jump to the start of the block as defined by the previous line. With "none" selected it will always jump all the way back to home. I don't know of any way to maintain block indenting and also combine the newline and jump to home all in a single keypress within SSMS, but something like autohotkey could do it. If you just want to create an "easier-to-reach-home-key", then go to tools>environment>keyboard and find the `edit.linestart` command

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@allmhuran

Thanks for the tips. Here are the solution for the problem.

Now: If I press Enter i go the the new line (inside the Block) if I press STRG + Enter then i go to the new line (position 1 outside the identtion above)

[image]